# Change background with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have the background image of a page change every 5 seconds. There are 5 images and I want them to loop.

I researched thoroughly here and tried different approaches. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code:

In my css I have:

```
html, body, #wrapper {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-image:url('images/indexbg01.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

and my javascript I have:

```
var imageArray = ['images/indexbg02.jpg', 'images/indexbg03.jpg', 
                  'images/indexbg04.jpg', 'images/indexbg05.jpg', 
                  'images/indexbg01.jpg'];
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeBgImage(){
    var imageUrl = "url('" + imageArray[imageIndex] + "')";
    $('body').css('background-image', imageUrl);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(changeBgImage, 5000);
```

I first had the imageUrl variable built in the line that follows, but I added this so I could check it was built ok.
In the chrome debugger, when I put a breakpoint on the line following the imageUrl build line, it stops nicely every 5 seconds, the imageUrl is built as it should, yet the background does not change.

Comment: could you put the html markup?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: I dont see the need for that, its just the headers, load the stylesheet/css file, the body, and load the javascript files. The Html has no styling in it whatsoever.

Comment: Just try using background instead of background-image

Comment: I asked it because don't know if the #wrapper is hiding the background, and the background actually changes.

Comment: By the looks of things Luis is right, the wrapper will be hiding the background as it is 100% in height with the first bg applied to it and you are changing the bg on the body. Either take the bg off your wrapper or change the jquery selector to be for your wrapper instead of body

Comment: Do you get errors in console? A 404 error on the images perhaps? Did you wrap your code in `$(document).ready`?

Comment: By the looks. But until we watch the markup, even basing our opinion on the CSS, we cannot guess if the issue is on the #wrapper div hiding the background.

Comment: See my answer. I was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Cv49/1/.

Enter and see. The only markup there is the:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

The only css modified is:

```
adding #wrapper to the selector.
```

See how background is overlapped by #wrapper's background.

Comment: @pmandell was right too. changing image-background to image did the trick. The wrapper is pretty wide to keep the content centered, but there were still sides showing, where I could see that the bg image now was changing. So giving the wrapper its own css removed the bg image from the wrapper. I also needed to add $('body').css('background-position', 'center center'); to the javascript because it wasn't centered anymore. Thanks you guys for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Works in the fiddle.It means you need to run script after page load like the fiddle does:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //your script
});
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cv49/)

Comment: Edit your fiddle since the code is different. Add a div#wrapper tag in the HTML, and add #wrapper in the CSS selector. Try and see: the wrapper has the "t" background, and behind, the body changes the background image.

Comment: I do see the `#wrapper` in his code but I also see that he is changing the body css with jQuery.Also he didnt provide his html.

Comment: Yes, he didn't, So we were all guessing. But see my answer with a modified version of ur fiddle.

Comment: I saw your edited fiddle.Yes its possible that the #wrapper div that he might be using is overlapping the body so the transitions are not visible to him .I am just answering for the possibility that the `#wrapper` is set by the asker knowingly and its not completely overlapping then its possible that his scripts are running before page load and inorder for his script to work properly he must load it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Unfortunately we don't have such information.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I personally have done in the past is to have a full page slideshow using jQuery. there are a number of versions of slideshow you can use from the internet. There are 100s of them some better than others. In the slideshow have it times to change every 5 seconds like you wanted. in your html wrap the slideshow in a div (#slideshow_background for example). wrap the rest of your html page into another wrapper (#content). in your CSS set the following..

```
#slideshow_background {
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
   position : initial;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

the put the css for your #content and set the z-index to 1 so that it lies above the slideshow.
hope this helps