# How to use the setInterval method in javascript to change the body's background color?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an assignment for my class and I would like to change the background color of the body, of my website, to random colors using the method: `setInterval` in my js page.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background with setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664190/change-background-with-setinterval)

Comment: Always show us your attempt and the initial code you have ''''written'''', it helps prove your effort and people to understand your question faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```html
<body style="height: 200px;background-color:yellow;">

</body>

      <script>
        function randomRGB() {
          var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 254) + 1);
          return x;
          }

        setInterval(function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor  = 'rgb(' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ')';
                  }, 2000);
      </script>
```

Comment: Had you used snippet, you would have known your code contains a few errors.

Comment: @JanLegner Thanks. my previous answer very bad as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a place for posting homeworks I will help you:

```js
function randomColor () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); // return random int from 0 to 255
}
setInterval(function () { // pass anonymous function to setInterval
  var r = randomColor(), g = randomColor(), b = randomColor();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}, 1000); // once every 1000ms
```

```html
some text
```

Also you can use another approach:

```js
setInterval(function () { // pass anonymous function to setInterval
  var rgb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16); // random hexa number from 0 to ffffff
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + ("00000" + rgb).substr(-6); // make sure we have exactly 6 hexa digits
}, 1000); // once every 1000ms
```

```html
some text
```

Comment: Very good this: `var rgb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16);`

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I do not think it would be enough... If you happen to generate `rgb = 4` for example, then the code will try to set invalid color.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
    var interval = 1000; // 1 second
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var color = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }, interval);
         
    // Remember to clear the interval with clearInterval(timer) if needed
}())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Colors!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the random color happens to be for example 4? `#4` is not a valid background color

Comment: I've updated the code to take care of trailing zeros, they where indeed not being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this `setInterval(function(){//code}, 1000)`

`1000` is the time in milliseconds. Each ´1sec´ the function will be executed.

In the following code I used `"#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);` to generate a random color

```js
setInterval(function(){document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);},500);
```

```css
body {height: 100%;}
```

```html
<body></body>
```